# AMCL randomly loses localisation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the `AMCL package with the following configuration:

```
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" clear_params="true">
    <param name="use_map_topic" value="$(arg use_map_topic)"/>
    
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff-corrected"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
   
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
   
    <param name="laser_max_range" value="-1.0"/> 
    <param name="laser_min_range" value="-1.0"/> 
    <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
   
   <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.01"/> <!-- 0.05-->
    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="4.0"/> <!-- 0.2-->
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.9"/> <!-- 0.2-->
   
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.2"/> <!-- 0.8 --> 
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/> <!-- 0.2-->
    <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
   
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="-0.2"/> <!-- 0.25 -->
    <param name="update_min_a" value="-0.5"/> <!-- 0.2 -->
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
   
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.3"/> <!-- 1.0 -->
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
```

The good thing is when the laser points matches exactly the map then the localisation is perfect, however when the laser points does not match exactly the map (even slight difference) the `AMCL` tries correcting the robot's position on the map but it sets the robot in a completely wrong position.

I think it is something about the AMCL configuration but I do not know exactly which parameter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319065/amcl-randomly-loses-localisation./) by [starter](https://answers.ros.org/users/27367/starter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2019-03-21**:
Check your odometry first, see [navigation troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Troubleshooting)

**Comment by [starter](https://answers.ros.org/users/27367/starter/) on 2019-03-22**:
The odometry works fine, the problem is that the robot relies too much on the map for the localisation, therefore if the laser points are not exactly matching the map, you can see the robot location starts jumping all over the map trying to match the laser points with the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for  `<param name="odom_model_type" value="diff-corrected"/>` type robot,

try to keep

```
 <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.005"/> 
 <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.005"/> 

 <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.01"/> 
 <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.005"/>
```

and if your map environment has low dynamic obstacles trusting your map`(param name="laser_z_hit")` a bit more might improve the localization.

and also try and increase the `"laser_max_beams"` to allow more laser points for localization.

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0